# Jest, path to custom .babelrc file

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

When I run my test, I do with this script:

```
"test": "jest --runInBand --forceExit",
```

If I put the `.babelrc` file in the root of the project, it works ok, but I need that file in some custom directory. How could I point to a new path?

For now, I'm just doing this:

```
"test": "cp customPath/.babelrc .babelrc; jest --runInBand --forceExit; rm .babelrc",
```

But I don't want to be copying and deleting the file. Is there a way to set the path?

EDIT: By the way, I can't put the babel config in `package.json`. It works ok but putting there the config but edit `package.json` is not an option.